# With preg_match you can cut a specific part of different sentences

Tags: php

I have a sentence of the same meaning written in different languages. In these sentences (:) next I just want to print the numbers on the screen.

Desired Output:

```
ArGe Puanı dağıtıldı: 50 vardı 0 kullanıldı
// OUT: 0/50
Przydzielono PP: 0 z 50
// OUT: 0/50
Punti ricerca assegnati: 0 su 50
// OUT: 0/50
Pontos de pesquisa distribuídos: 0 de 50
// OUT: 0/50
Puntos de investigación asignados: 0 de 50
// OUT: 0/50
Přidělené studijní body: 0 z 50
// OUT: 0/50
Использовано очков прогресса: 0 из 50
// OUT: 0/50
Point(s) de recherche attribué(s) : 0 sur 50
// OUT: 0/50
Research Points used: 0/50
// OUT: 0/50
Forschungspunkte verteilt: 0 von 50
// OUT: 0/50
Képességpont kiosztva: 0 / 50
// OUT: 0/50
```

I solved my problem. This code works for me. How can this code be shorter?

Attempt:

```
<?php 
$re = '/[0-9]+/';
$str = 'Research Points used: 11/50';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

if( $matches[0][0] == 50 && $matches[0][0] == 50){
    $Arge = 50;
}
if( $matches[0][0] == 50 ){
    $Arge = $matches[0][1];
} else {
    $Arge = $matches[0][0];
}

echo $Arge;
?>
```

Comment: Please show us what you've already tried and what your current result looks like

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6d0ad2ca7f342e8eaa55939fb25bc430f94d6fc3    


I solved my problem. This code works for me.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the line `if( $matches[0][0] == 50 && $matches[0][0] == 50){`?

Comment: If you believe that the code works correctly, consider presenting your work (with its unit tests) in a more-complete fashion over at [codereview.se].  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.  Before you do that, make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) first, as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".

Comment: 50/50 for every 2 values in the text is 50. The Fixed Value is 50.